# Save and reuse TfidfVectorizer in scikit learn

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, pickle, text-mining

I am using TfidfVectorizer in scikit learn to create a matrix from text data. Now I need to save this object to reuse it later. I tried to use pickle, but it gave the following error.

```
loc=open('vectorizer.obj','w')
pickle.dump(self.vectorizer,loc)
*** TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

I tried using `joblib` in sklearn.externals, which again gave similar error. Is there any way to save this object so that I can reuse it later?

Here is my full object:

```py
class changeToMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self,ngram_range=(1,1),tokenizer=StemTokenizer()):
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
        self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=ngram_range,analyzer='word',lowercase=True,
                                          token_pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+',strip_accents='unicode',
                                          tokenizer=tokenizer)

    def load_ref_text(self,text_file):
        textfile = open(text_file,'r')
        lines = textfile.readlines()
        textfile.close()
        sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
        sentences = [item.strip().strip('.') for item in sent_tokenizer.tokenize(' '.join(lines).strip())]
        #vectorizer is transformed in this step
        chk2 = pd.DataFrame(self.vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences1).toarray())
        return sentences, [chk2]

    def get_processed_data(self,data_loc):
        ref_sentences,ref_dataframes=self.load_ref_text(data_loc)
        loc = open("indexedData/vectorizer.obj","w")
        pickle.dump(self.vectorizer,loc) #getting error here
        loc.close()
        return ref_sentences, ref_dataframes
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, it's better to leave the import at the top of your code instead of within your class:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
class changeToMatrix(object):
  def __init__(self,ngram_range=(1,1),tokenizer=StemTokenizer()):
    ...
```

Next `StemTokenizer` don't seem to be a canonical class. Possibly you've got it from http://sahandsaba.com/visualizing-philosophers-and-scientists-by-the-words-they-used-with-d3js-and-python.html or maybe somewhere else so ***we'll assume it returns a list of strings***.

```
class StemTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ignore_set = {'footnote', 'nietzsche', 'plato', 'mr.'}

    def __call__(self, doc):
        words = []
        for word in word_tokenize(doc):
            word = word.lower()
            w = wn.morphy(word)
            if w and len(w) > 1 and w not in self.ignore_set:
                words.append(w)
        return words
```

Now to answer your actual question, it's possible that you need to open a file in byte mode before dumping a pickle, i.e.:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(0,2),analyzer='word',lowercase=True, token_pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+',strip_accents='unicode',tokenizer=word_tokenize)
>>> vectorizer
TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(0, 2), norm=u'l2', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
        stop_words=None, strip_accents='unicode', sublinear_tf=False,
        token_pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
        tokenizer=<function word_tokenize at 0x7f5ea68e88c0>, use_idf=True,
        vocabulary=None)
>>> with open('vectorizer.pk', 'wb') as fin:
...     pickle.dump(vectorizer, fin)
... 
>>> exit()
alvas@ubi:~$ ls -lah vectorizer.pk 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alvas alvas 763 Jun 15 14:18 vectorizer.pk
```

**Note**: Using the `with` idiom for i/o file access automatically closes the file once you get out of the `with` scope.

Regarding the issue with `SnowballStemmer()`, note that `SnowballStemmer('english')` is an object while the stemming function is `SnowballStemmer('english').stem`.

**IMPORTANT**:

- `TfidfVectorizer`'s tokenizer parameter expects to take a string and return a list of string
- But Snowball stemmer does not take a string as input and return a list of string.

So you will need to do this:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english').stem
>>> def stem_tokenize(text):
...     return [stemmer(i) for i in word_tokenize(text)]
... 
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(0,2),analyzer='word',lowercase=True, token_pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+',strip_accents='unicode',tokenizer=stem_tokenize)
>>> with open('vectorizer.pk', 'wb') as fin:
...     pickle.dump(vectorizer, fin)
...
>>> exit()
alvas@ubi:~$ ls -lah vectorizer.pk 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alvas alvas 758 Jun 15 15:55 vectorizer.pk
```

Comment: Opening the file in byte mode did not work. But I figured out the issue. It was the StemTokenizer class making the issue. While initializing that class, I had given "self.snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')" . When I changed this part into the __call__ part , it worked. I am not sure why it worked though.

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever the tokenizer function is, it returns a list of string.

Comment: It returns a list of strings only. The error was removed when I changed `self.snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')` to `snowball_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')`. Basically I removed this from the attributes of the class and the error was fixed.

Comment: Ahhh. it's because `SnowballStemmer('english')` is an object, what you need is an iterable using `SnowballStemmer('english').stem`

Comment: Hi! I am trying to save a Pickle for transforming text with TfidfVectorizer, it is 76MB size and i need to reduce it to 10MB. Does the parameter dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>  will help to reduce size?

Answer (score 5):

If you arrived at this Q/A to look into pickling a Vectorizer to save space on disk, you can either use `joblib` that comes with scikit-learn with `compress=True` or use the built-in `gzip` module along with `pickle`. A working example would look like the following. It compresses the file to be at least 2 times smaller for my use cases.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import joblib
import pickle
import gzip

data = fetch_20newsgroups().data
tvec = TfidfVectorizer()
tvec.fit(data)

# option #1
joblib.dump(tvec, 'vectorizer.pkl', compress=True)

# option #2
with gzip.open('vectorizer.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tvec, f)
```